# where is the output goes when running as a background process?

Tags: linux

My process output some log information to the console windows. When I run it as a background process, where can I find the output logs?

Comment: I suspect nowhere. Background processes don't have access to a terminal, that's why it's advised to close(stdin, stdout, stderr) when writing a daemon etc...

Comment: should probably asked here: http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 23):

Depends on the process and how you started it. If it writes to `stdout` (which is probable, given that the output is usually to the terminal), you can redirect the output to a file with

```
command > logfile &
```

If you also want to log error message from `stderr`, do

```
command > logfile 2> errorlogfile &
```

or

```
command > logfile 2>&1 &
```

to get everything in one file.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a **systemd** service you can run `journalctl -u <service-name>`

> You can check for latest logs by clicking **SHIFT + G **
>
> > Make sure systems is installed `apt-get install systemd`